# Importing a scenario xml from another machine in ODI

Tags: linux, scp, oracle-data-integrator

I am trying to import a scenario to ODI from another machine (a export file from a folder). I dont want to copy the export files. Below is the ODI Tools command I use in a procedure but the import fails. Do we have any workaround for this?

**OdiImportScen "-FILE_NAME=scp://user@host:22/folder_name/SCEN_FILE.xml" "-IMPORT_MODE=SYNONYM_INSERT_UPDATE" "-IMPORT_SCHEDULE=NO" "-IMPORT_WITHOUT_CIPHER_DATA=YES"

Error Message:
ODI-30084: File "scp://user@host:22/folder_name/SCEN_FILE.xml" does not exist

Answer (score 2):

scp protocol is generally used in scp program and not in other tools. ODI Tools are written in Java and there is not support for locations prefixed with the scp protocol `scp://` in this language (or anywhere as far as I know).

So there are 2 solutions :

1. First scp the file on the local ODI machine (where the agent runs if you plan to automate it), they use OdiImportScen locally.
2. Expose a network drive where the file is stored and mount it on your local ODI machine